# Elegant way to express xs.sort.head

Tags: scala, collections

Several combinations of methods on a collection can be expressed more succinctly in Scala.  For example, `xs.filter(f).headOption` can be expressed as `xs.find(f)`, and `xs.map.filter` can usually be better expressed through `xs.collect`.

I find myself writing `xs.sortWith(f).head`, and this feels to me like the sort of thing that could be expressed as a single method, "find me the least element in this collection, according to this sorting function".

However, I can't see any obvious methods on `Seq` or `TraversableLike`.  Is there a single method that captures my intent, or is `.sort.head` the more elegant way to find the "least" element?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
scala> val xs = List("hello", "bye", "hi")
xs: List[java.lang.String] = List(hello, bye, hi)

scala> xs.sortWith(_.length < _.length).head
res10: java.lang.String = hi

scala> xs.min(Ordering.fromLessThan[String](_ > _))
res11: java.lang.String = hi

scala> xs.min(Ordering.by((_: String).length))
res12: java.lang.String = hi

scala> xs.minBy(_.length)
res13: java.lang.String = hi
```

Comment: `minBy`, of course.  I was looking for other functions that took an `A => A => Boolean` as per `sortWith`, but this really isn't necessary for my use-case.